# Where in the registry are options for Visual Studio 2013 extensions stored?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I know that Visual Studio 2015 extension options are (or at least can be) stored in the registry with the following key:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ApplicationPrivateSettings\ExtensionName`

I have unsuccessfully searched the registry for a VS2013 equivalent such as:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ApplicationPrivateSettings\ExtensionName`

Is there a registry entry where options for Visual Studio extensions for VS2013 are stored ?

Comment: I also check it in my side, it really has no that path for the VS2013, I also check the VS2010 and VS2012, it also have no that path. It seems that the VS2015 really changed the old way how VS load the Extensions: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2009/12/07/bootstrapping-of-vs-packages-and-vsix-extensions-in-vs2010/